# Invalid Credential - Unity Firebase

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication, sms, credentials

I've been developing an app in Unity for the past two years and only now realized that my phone authentication didn't work correctly. This is because I'm developing on Android and therefore I've always only seen the results of "verificationCompleted" and not codeSent.

In other words, putting the SMS code in manually doesn't work. It says that the credential is invalid. IT ISN'T! The code is right. The thing is, that I copied my code over to another project, and then it worked perfectly. Therefore it's probably nothing wrong with my code. What could've happened here? Also, everything worked fine, until I was supposed to verify the code itself. I got the SMS etc.

When can you get the error, invalid credential, when the code isn't wrong?
Feels like I've tried everything!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's some pictures of my code as well. Some stuff has nothing to do with the authentication, but yeah...

```
    public void VerifyPhoneNumber(string _phoneNumber)
    {
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Auth is {0}, AuthenticationController is {1} and GameController is {2}.", auth, authenticationController, null));

        

        var phoneAuthProvider = Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
        phoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(_phoneNumber, phoneAuthTimeoutMs, null,
            verificationCompleted: (cred) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Verification Completed");

                MutualUiController.mutualUI.loadingPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(HandleSignInResult);
            },
            verificationFailed: (error) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Verification Failed" + error);
            },
            codeSent: (id, token) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Verification Code Sent");

                phoneAuthVerificationId = id;
                

                Debug.Log("ID: " + id + ", Token: " + token.ToString());

                if (SceneController.currentScene == Scene.AuthenticationPage)
                {
                    MutualUiController.mutualUI.loadingPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                    Transform panel = GameObject.Find("AuthPageUI").GetComponent<AuthPageUI>().verificationPanel;
                    panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                }
            },
            codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Code Auto Timeout");
            });
    }

    //verificationCompleted: (cred) =>
    //        {
    //            //Debug.Log("Verification Completed");

    //            //MutualUiController.mutualUI.loadingPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    //            //auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(HandleSignInResult);
    //        },

    public void VerifyRecievedPhoneCode(string recievedCodeInput)
    {
        var phoneAuthProvider = Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
        var cred = phoneAuthProvider.GetCredential(phoneAuthVerificationId, recievedCodeInput);

        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(HandleSignInResult);
    }
```